# How to change results to display a different name SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there a way in which I can change the way in which I see results of my query?

I'll use an example. I have a table with the id of a market, and then the name of the market, and the **sport ID**. I want the the **sport id** to be displayed as a sport name instead.

```
SELECT id, name, sport_id FROM markets where sport_id = 2;
```

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM markets where sport_id = 2 as 'Football';
```

But that didn't work. I don't want to modify the results like an update would, I just want the results to be displayed as football instead of **sport_id 2**.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is a sports table, would a join work?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: You probably have a `sports`table as well which has `id` and `name` columns. You then need to do a `JOIN` - google SQL joins. You're query will be something like `SELECT markets.ID, markets.name AS marketsname, sports.name AS sportsname FROM Markets INNER JOIN Sports ON Markets.Sport_id = Sports.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do have only one table and like to give Alias then go for Query 1

```
SELECT id, name, sport_id AS 'sport name' FROM markets where sport_id = 2;
```

or

if you do have two different tables then Go for it
You need to join with other table as given below

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, t.sport_name
FROM markets m
JOIN other_Table t ON m.sport_id = t.sport_Id
where m.sport_id = 2;
```

I hope this might be helpful to solve your Issue.

Comment: @PKGrem if you find the answer correct then please upvote so it can be helpful to other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `JOIN` to your `sports` table, something like:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, s.sport_name
FROM markets m
JOIN sports s 
  ON m.sport_id = s.sport_Id
where m.sport_id = 2;
```

Comment: Yep that worked the charm, just joined the table and added in the name in the select, thanks a lot, can't believe I just saw this as an oversight!

Comment: @user3723217 Happens to everyone!